# Figures, texts and captions outside margins

Tags: floats, captions, margins

I'm having problens in adjusting figures inside the expected space for the text, since they are getting outside the margins. The captions and some lines of text have the same problems.

Here's my code:

```
%%%  DOCUMENT SETTINGS  %%%
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %page type
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry} %margins
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indenting package
\setstretch{1.5} %between lines spacement
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm} %first line indentation

%font and language configs
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} %letter type
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %normal acentuation
%\usepackage{arial}
    % using pseudoarial font Helvetica.
    \usepackage{helvet}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%image config
\usepackage{graphicx} % Image using package
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{caption} % Image, tables, and others captions.
\usepackage{subcaption} % SubImage package. More then one per line.

%math config
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% text packages
\usepackage{sectsty} % section title
\sectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} %changing section fontsize
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % no hyphenation
\usepackage{microtype} % better justification

\captionsetup{labelfont=bf} % Caption labeling in bold

\begin{document}

%%% INTRODUÇÃO
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Introdução}

... Um conceito importante ao se falar de velocidade de reações é o tempo de meia vida ($\tau$), definido como o tempo que a reação leva para atingir metade da concentração inicial....

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Mecanismo das reações de $\rm S_N$.}
    %sn2
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subcaption{Mecanismo de reação $\rm S_N$2 para a hidroxilação do clorometano}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption*{Fonte: ....}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage} \hspace{.1\textwidth}
    %sn1
    \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    \centering
    \subcaption{Mecanismo de reação $\rm S_N$1 para a hidroxilação do (S)-3-Bromo-3-metilhexano.}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption*{Fonte: ....}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{minipage}
    \label{fig:sn}
    \end{figure}

Alguns nucleófilos mais comuns são ..., estes estando em ordem de maior reatividade, para a menor reatividade.

\end{document}
```

I'm sorry for the long code, it's because the text is also big, and it's my standard package declaration. Also I'm sorry if has some duplicate of this problem, I'm searsching a solution for a few days now and didn't found any.

EDIT:

I've tried unsucssesfuly to reproduce the problem in a short file, so I'm uploading the code in overleaf.
I've substituted most of the real text by the dummy one, and the images by the samples ones.
Trying to reproduce the error I've found the the problem of the overfull lines is a thing of \usepackage[none]{hyphenat}, that if any one knows how to solve would help me a lot.
And I've also found that the problem of the images, tables, and floats in general comprimising the margins is that in somewhere, somehow the \textwidth and \textcolumn have been redefined to be more than one line.
The last but no least important error that I've found is that my document is not indented, so I also would apreciate help with this.

[Overleaf project](https://pt.overleaf.com/read/yxpbnrcppkfk)

**UPDATE**

Seems that removing the `\abstract` command all the problems where solved. I don't know why, but thank you all. You were all very helpfull and taught me great things.

Comment: welcome to tex.se! after removing errors in your code (not defined title, spurious `}` and use `demo` options for your image i cand reproduce your problem. please, make your document example minimal and use  test images from `graphicx` package (we haven't your images) abd add `showframe` option to `geometry` packages and show result, which you obtain with your document.

Comment: @Zarko I'm sorry, in the actual document I have a title, and I also copied the parts, so somethings should be naturaly wrong, and thanks for the tips, I'm going to pay attention to them the next time. I also could not reproduce the problem in the demo text, so I'm clippling an overleaf copy of my archive with dumy text where it should be the real one.

Comment: `\textwidth` -> `\linewidth`? Off-topic: `\rm` is several decades obsolete.

Comment: @cfr nope. Did not solve the problem.
What should I use insted of rm? I'm quite new on LaTeX.

Comment: @liuzp, Yes, your document **is** indented. There is something after `\begin{document}` that was making is _less_ indented than you intended. A MWE on your part may clarify that.

Comment: @liuzp `\textrm{}` or `\mathrm{}` if you really need appearance markup (rather than semantic). `\rm` shouldn't be used with LaTeX 2e.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the `subfigure` environment with the `subcaption` command. The environment is described later in the package [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/caption/subcaption.pdf).

You had to use the environment correctly, remove the `minipage`, and ajust the width.

I made your example [minimal](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe), since your issue is only with the figures.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %page type
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=2cm, left=3cm, right=2cm]{geometry} % really nice abnt margins
%\usepackage{setspace} %why this if you're using `\baselinestretch`?
\usepackage{indentfirst} %indenting package
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} %interline spacing between lines 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm} %first line indentation

\usepackage{float} % tables and figures in multicols.

%font and language configs
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} %letter type -- *no*, it's *hyphenation*
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input utf8 characters directly
%\usepackage{arial}
    % using pseudoarial font Helvetica. **No**, the clone is Arial, not the other way round
%   \usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage{tgheros} %somewhat better
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
    %\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % not needed, already default with tgheros

%image config
\usepackage{graphicx} % Image using package
\usepackage{caption} % Image, tables, and others captions.
\usepackage{subcaption} % SubImage package. More then one per line.
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Wraping figure inside text

\usepackage{blindtext} % lorem ipsum

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Comportamente da concentração e da velocidade de reações de diferentes ordens.}
    % C x t
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth} 
\centering
    \subcaption{Decaimento da concentração relativa em função do tempo para reações de ordens diferentes.}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{fig:ReactionOrders}
    \caption*{Fonte: Autoria própria}
    \end{subfigure}
 %\hspace{.1\textwidth}
    % v x c
\hfill 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth} \centering
    \subcaption{Decaimento da velocidade relativa em função da concentração para reações de ordens diferentes.}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \label{fig:SpeedOrders}
    \caption*{Fonte: Autoria própria}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}

\blindtext


\end{document}
```